# sprintf-like function for CUDA device-side code?

Tags: cuda, printf

I could not find anything in internet. Due to the fact that it is possible to use `printf` in a `__device__` function I am wondering if there is a `sprintf` like function due to the fact that `printf` is "using" the result from `sprintf` to be displayed in `stdout`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there isn't anything built into CUDA for this.

Within CUDA the implementation of device `printf` is a special case and does not use the same mechanisms as the C library printf.

Comment: Indeed, http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#formatted-output says "Final formatting of the printf() output takes place on the host system." so they did not even have to implement a "sprintf-like function" in device code. I hear the old cuPrintf worked that way. And of course you can find lots of implementations of (simplified) sprintf that will compile with cuda.

Comment: While it's true that the actually-printing part is indeed a special case and not at all like sprintf, there's the parsing of the format-string, and possibly some more marshalling-in-a-buffer code which could perhaps be shared with a `sprintf()` implementation.

Comment: @masterxilo “of course you can find lots of implementations of...” — this doesn’t appear to be true.

Comment: @boreo https://github.com/mpredfearn/simple-printf/blob/master/printf.c

Comment: @masterxilo : I eventually went with the more popular [mpaland `printf()`](https://github.com/mpaland/printf/), but since that repository got abandoned it, I unified all of the forks, took on maintainership, and [fixed many bugs and other issues](https://github.com/eyalroz/printf/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed). This resulted in: [`eyalroz/printf`](https://github.com/eyalroz/printf) which I can now recommend as a stand-alone implementation for any system.

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf()`, `snprintf()` and additional `printf()`-family functions are now available on the development branch of the **CUDA Kernel Author's Toolkit**, a.k.a. [cuda-kat](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-kat/tree/development). Signatures:

```c++
namespace kat {

__device__ int sprintf(char* s, const char* format, ...);
__device__ int snprintf(char* s, size_t n, const char* format, ...);

}
```

... and they do exactly what you would expect. In particular, they support the C standard features which CUDA `printf()` *does not*, and then some  (e.g. specifying a string argument's field width using an extra argument; format specifiers for `size_t`, and `ptrdiff_t`, and printing in base-2).

Caveat: I am the author of cuda-kat, so I'm biased...

---

<sub>Always prefer `snprintf()` which takes the buffer size over`sprintf()` which might overflow.</sub>